# Data in XML file is different in browser and notepad

Tags: c#, xml, windows

I have an application which uses msi to setup. It creates a XML file with input data from user while setting up my application. Then I deleted the app. The user setup the app again but with different data. But when user opens the XML file with browser it shows the deleted setup's data. But when user opens the XML file with notepad it show the current data.

Do you guys have any idea?

I am using VS 2022 and to create the msi I used Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022 extension.

I will try to share the data about your comments.

I also changed the XML with notepad and still same. Also deleted it and added it manuelly but still same.

Comment: Check browser cache, clear it out and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: 1) Does the problem persist if you try a different browser for viewing the XML? Or the same browser, but in Private / Incognito mode? 2) Where is the XML located on the user's HDD, and can you verify that the file is actually being overwritten on new installations? 3) Are there any traces of your application located in `%windir%\installer`, and if there are, is the old XML there, as well?

Comment: 1) When I open the file with Edge it's the one i want but explorer shows the old data. 2) It's located in program files x86 and when i install the app it creates a new XML file. 3) There was a sourcehash in %windir%\installer about my app but no XML.

Comment: Also when I install app in another folder it works perfectly